Django User not inheriting Group permissions
I have a TestCase that i'm testing permissions on. I don't understand how this test is failing where it's failing:
        # Make sure group has permission
        group_permissions = self.my_group.permissions.filter(codename="view_mymodel")
        self.assertEqual(len(group_permissions), 1)

        print("Group Permissions:")
        for permission in group_permissions:
            print(permission)

        # Make sure user is in group
        user_groups = self.user.groups.filter(name="My User Group")
        self.assertEqual(len(user_groups), 1)

        user_permissions = self.user.get_all_permissions()
        print("User Permissions:")
        for permission in user_permissions:
            print(permission)

        # Make sure user has permission
        self.assertTrue(self.user.has_perm("myapp.view_mymodel"))

This is failing at the last assertion. I can see the permission is set for the group but when i call get_all_permissions(), nothing shows up. That makes no sense because get_all_permissions() is suppose to return all permissions on both the User and the group.

Turns out this was a caching issue. If I re-authenticate the user after setting permissions, I see the test passing.
        # Make sure user is in group
        user_groups = self.user.groups.filter(id=self.my_group.id)
        self.assertEqual(len(user_groups), 1)
        
        # Refresh cache on the user
        self.user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.user.id)

        user_permissions = self.kcs_user.get_all_permissions()
        print("User Permissions:")
        for permission in user_permissions:
            print(permission)

        # Make sure user has permission
        self.assertTrue(self.user.has_perm("myapp.view_mymodel"))

        # Re-authenticate the client to refresh permissions on the request User
        self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)

Problem solved!
